# Creating a POJO from CSV where a field is an Enum

Tags: bindy

I'm using Bindy to create a Pojo from the following CSV file where side is an Enum:

```
orderId,symbol,side,price,quantity
1, MSFT, SELL, 19, 8
2, MSFT, SELL, 20, 4
3, MSFT, BUY, 16, 16
```

```
public enum Side {
    BUY,
    SELL
}
```

Here is my Camel route:

```
 @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:///Users/username/src/main/resources?fileName=orders.csv&noop=true&delay=1m")
                .unmarshal()
                .bindy(BindyType.Csv, Order.class).id("convertCsvToOrder")
                .to("kafka:" + "{{kafka.topic.neworder}}" + "{{kafka.broker.location}}").id("sendNewOrderToTopic")
                .routeId("new-order-csv");
    }
```

I've spent a long time reading the Apache Camel documentation but cannot find examples of how to provide a converter so that the Side Enum in the Pojo is constructed correctly. At the moment I'm getting the following exception when Bindy attempts to parse the CSV. Appreciate if anyone can provide guidance. Thanks.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parsing error detected for field defined at the position: 3, line: 1
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.setDataFieldValue(BindyCsvFactory.java:257) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.bind(BindyCsvFactory.java:185) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat.lambda$consumeFile$0(BindyCsvDataFormat.java:243) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat.unmarshal(BindyCsvDataFormat.java:176) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:69) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:223) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:187) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) [camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.xxx.yyy.model.Side. SELL
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.format.factories.EnumFormatFactory$EnumFormat.parse(EnumFormatFactory.java:49) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.format.factories.EnumFormatFactory$EnumFormat.parse(EnumFormatFactory.java:36) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.setDataFieldValue(BindyCsvFactory.java:252) ~[camel-bindy-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to work out what to do here...

There's an annotation called @BindyConverter which you can apply to fields. I applied this annotation to the field 'Side' then created a class called SideConverter which performs the conversions.

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", crlf = "\r\n",  quoting = true, skipFirstLine = true)
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @DataField(pos = 1, required = true)
    private final Long orderId;

    @DataField(pos = 2, required = true)
    private final String symbol;

    @DataField(pos = 3, required = true)
    @BindyConverter(SideConverter.class)
    private final Side side;

    @DataField(pos = 4, required = true)
    private final Integer price;

    @DataField(pos = 5, required = true)
    private final Integer quantity;

    public Order(long orderId, String symbol, Side side, int price, int quantity) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.side = side;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
```

```
public class SideConverter implements Format<Enum> {

    @Override
    public String format(Enum object) throws Exception {
        return object.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Enum parse(String string) throws Exception {
        Enum parsedValue = null;
        if (string.equals("BUY")) {
            parsedValue = Side.BUY;
        }

        if (string.equals("SELL")) {
            parsedValue = Side.SELL;
        }
        return parsedValue;
    }
}
```